# AWS CodePipeline never triggers BlazeMeter properly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, blazemeter

I setup a BlazeMeter test action in my AWS CodePipeline. The setup worked fine, sending me over to the BlazeMeter site to authenticate and select a test. But when I run the pipeline, it just sits at the BlazeMeter action "In Progress" until it times out. I've opened a ticket with BlazeMeter support but they don't seem to see anything. Any one have experience getting this to work? Cloudtrail and the CodePipeline logs don't have any detailed log info about the requests going to BlazeMeter, so I'm kind of stuck.

Comment: I have the same issue

Answer (score 1):

Typically a TimeOutConnectionError occurs when the firewall does not allow access to a specific URL.  Since you can get as far as authenticating in Blazemeter, I would focus specifically on ensuring the engines can reach your application server through your firewall, which may require whitelisting some IPs (depending on your setup).